# Jenkins + Github -- Trigger java program

Tags: java, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am a novice with Jenkins and wanted to know if it is possible to trigger a Java program (e.g. a hello world program) with Jenkins. For example, when any change is made in GitHub repository Jenkins should trigger this hello world program. Is this even possible using Jenkins? Can someone please help me with this? I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: By triggering the hello world program you mean to trigger the execution or compilation of the program?

Comment: I would like to execute my hello world program....basically this java program is already made in eclipse I would like to execute it whenever a change is made in GitHub via Jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

1.You can write shell script in post-recieve hook of GIT repository.

2.Whenever you push the code this hook is executed, your script can remotely call build-JOB on your Jenkins using jenkins-cli.jar

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI

3.you can use maven or gradle build for your project.

4.Artifacts created from build job (ear,war,etc) can be deployed onto your application server using Jenkins Job(some shell scripting again)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Jenkins GitHub plugin to get notified when a push is made to GitHub, more details here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

- **GitHub Webhook** from GitHub Plugin
- Build -> **Execute shell** -> Command